# Regular expression for finding currency values but not dates in text

Tags: c#, regex

I have text like the following two example strings

```
this book was sold for 12.00 on 12.12.2010
he paid 12.12.2010 , and puchased an amount of 15.00
```

From these lines I want to capture the amount, but not the dates using a regular expression.

Comment: This does not make sense. You want to get the 12.00 but not the 12.12.2010? And get the 15.00 but not the 12.12.2010?

Comment: You should probably hire a couple of persons to process this "data".

Comment: are sentence construction always the same ? In order words, wouldn't it be simpler to split string by space and get values from well known indexes ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
\d+\.\d{2}(?![.\d])
```

if all you need is to distinguish between dates in *exactly* this format and currency amounts in *exactly* this format.

This regex looks for the pattern *digits, dot, two-digits* but only if it's *not* followed by either another dot or another digit (to prevent the dates from matching).

Quick PowerShell test:

[image]

Update for short dates in the form `dd.mm.yy` (just in case you need them):

```
(?<![.\d])\d+\.\d{2}(?![.\d])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\b\d+\.\d{2}(?!\.?\d)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vdug)

`\b` is a word boundary, this ensures that there is a non word character (includes also digits) before the first digit.

`\d+\.\d{2}` is at least one digit, followed by a dot and two other digits.

`(?!\.?\d)` is a negative look ahead that ensures that there is no digit OR no dot followed by a digit ahead. This would allow the amount to be at the end of the sentence.

Working c# code:

```
String s = "this book was sold for 12.00 on 12.12.2010";

Regex r = new Regex(@"\b\d+\.\d{2}(?!\.?\d)");

Console.WriteLine(r.Matches(s)[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Why shouldn't this work with .net regexes (I know it will)? The only thing I could imagine that you don't use verbatim strings, try this `@"\b\d+\.\d{2}(?!\.?\d)"`

Comment: I tried it in Expresso and it didn't work, whereas Joey's did. But I just tried it again and now it works... not sure what I did wrong the first time

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(?:\s|^)\d+\.\d+(?:\s|$)
```

It gives two matches in my test:

```
12.00 
15.00
```