# Regular expression for currency finding from the text of line

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for finding currency values but not dates in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430069/regular-expression-for-finding-currency-values-but-not-dates-in-text)

Hi this is my text can u please provide reg ex for finding currency only as shown below:

```
97.38
86.16
3,259.81
28,781.07
```

problem here is it is getting value from date also because it is in the of the currency so it should restrict the value from date

Ex text:

```
13/07/2011  EA35906558 - 13.07.11   8054    97.38
14/07/2011  EA35906566-14.07.11 8054    86.16
14/08@011   VP40853570 - 14.08.11   8122    3,259.81
14108/2011  VP50433270-14.08.11 8122-   28,781.07
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Why don't you work on your previous question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430069/regular-expression-for-finding-currency-values-but-not-dates-in-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430069/regular-expression-for-finding-currency-values-but-not-dates-in-text)? There are three answers to this, but not a single respond from you.

Answer (score 1):

Are the numbers always at the end of the line? If so:

```
\s([0-9]+\,?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)$
```

http://rubular.com/r/8z7r8epLk9

Comment: That text will be at any where not only in the end please check it is not getting in the middle of text

Answer (score 1):

That is actually very easy:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"([\d.,]+)\s*$").Groups[1].Value;
```

Provided you care only for the last number of the string. If you apply the above in each line you will get your currency. No need for special format or anything. Implementation is .NET but you can change it to anything you want.

Comment: Here i can not use any coding , it is already developed tool , for that i have to pass reqex and text then it will the matched results so for that i am thing different